# Cloud Run doesn’t work with Express static middleware

Tags: express, google-cloud-run

I have an express container that serves static files and it works perfectly when built and deployed locally. However, when I build and deploy it to Cloud Run, the dynamic html is returned but static assets like css files are 404. Are there any known limitations with Cloud Runthat May be contributing to this difficult-to-diagnose issue?

Comment: Isn't it the case that Cloud Run is used to serve microservices/REST services and as such would be a poor choice to serve static data?  Isn't the Cloud Run a stateless request?  Wouldn't it be better to serve the static data from GCS?  I'm wondering if the problem might also be manifesting because the returned URLs don't include the dynamic PORT value?

Comment: Run the same container on your local machine using Docker or Podman. If you have the same problem, then you know it is not Cloud Run. I have deployed hundreds of Cloud Run services. There is nothing that I am aware of that will cause your problem by Cloud Run.

Comment: @Kolban - the returned URLS do not need the dynamic port number. The dynamic port is only needed for the application's listener.

Comment: Yes, serving static from express is a bad idea in prod. This is for development.

Comment: This might be a related useful article ... https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-run-a-static-site-on-google-cloud-run-345713ca4b40

Would you be able to post a link or example to an illustrative recipe and scripts?  Without access to those we can't say where the issue may be.  If we could attempt a trivial recreate, that would be ideal.  Maybe a minimalist cut-down app that (as simply as possible) illustrates the issue may help us.

Comment: Share your configuation/code. We can't answer this question without details.

Comment: Hi all, I found the issue. My static files were .gitignored and I didn’t realize there was an implicit .gcloudignore that extended .gitignore, so on build it was stripping my static assets. By default google cloud build seems to ignore the union of .dockerignore and .gitignore.

Answer (score 1):

Searching the problem, I found this issue and realize the correct answer is masked because it's in the last comment on SO.

Google cloud use a file called .gcloudignore to not ignore some files while uploading.
If the file does not exist, .git and .gitignore files are used, and typically some assets will be in your .gitignore.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore